# How to merge the values of an array into multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

sorry for the title of my question i really don't know how to emphasize my problem but here is the sample array:

[image]

and here is my code

```
foreach ($_POST['noofguest'] as $keyg => $valueg) {

                echo $valueg. "<br />";
```

}

```
        foreach($_POST['room_no'] as $key => $value){

            foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){

                echo $value2 . " has " . $valueg . "<br />";
            }


        }
```

and the result of this is:

```
1

2

56 has 1

57 has 1
```

but this is not the result that i want, what i want is

```
1

2

56 has 1

57 has 2
```

is this possible??

Comment: If you have `'noofguest' => array(0=>'2',1=>'1')` how are you getting `1 2` and not `2 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second loop, you want to receive the same index of the `room_no` but only inside the `noofguest` array. So that's exactly what you should do:

```
foreach($_POST['room_no'] as $key => $value)
  foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
    echo $value2 . " has " . $_POST['noofguest'][$key2] . "<br />";
```